Where does the common wire for my humidifier connect to my furnace board?
I am installing a Digi Mist humidifier to a gas furnace. My circuit board is a D345780P01 control panel. Where does common wire connect?
Bottom of panel:


Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your title should be a clear, concise question. Your post should contain supporting details.

It connects on the part not shown on your picture (a transformer)

Look at the pic below. A tech told me the hot wire goes on the W and the common on the C on the panel board

The C wire connects to the screw label C on the board

ebay.com

Thanks. So If I connect the 24v hot wire to the W? Instead of using the transformer that was included?

@JerryMcDonald transformer that was included you did not say you had one. Yes you can use the transformer or connect to the board. W is the heating command (24 V)
